# How to perform IN Query in Azure - Android

Tags: android, sql, azure

How do I perform IN Query through my Android Code which pulls data from Easy Table .

Below is my Query which I executed in my Query Editor in Azure but , I cannot find a way to perform in Azure - Android Code via my MobileServiceSyncTable and QueryOperations

Query :

```
select * from Table3 where someId IN ( select someID from Table2 where UserID = '1' )
```

Should I perform it via code or is there a way to fetch such data by Azure Portal directly .